Parallel access and writing of MemoryCache in C# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with some controllers and want to use a MemoryCache to share date between different API calls.
if (!_cache.TryGetValue("myCache", out List<String>? myList))
{
    myList = new List<String>();
}

var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2),
    SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
    Size = 1,
};

myList?.Add(someString);

_cache.Set("myCache", myList, cacheEntryOptions);

My problem: if there are many request incoming in parallel, each request gets the list correctly from the cache, adds its string and writes the value back into the cache.
But in the meantime between getting and writing, another request had read the old list from the cache, added its string and so on... and in the end, only one string was added to the list.
Is there a solution or a pattern I can use to prevent this? So that in the end each request's string was added to the shared list in the cache?

You may be able to detect this using this function: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.addorgetexisting?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0 but it will only help you to identify the problem, not to solve it (as soon as 3 requests in parallel access the entry, it will cause a problem). The only solution I see is some kind of mutex, or a own class, which takes care about this.

I think you'll want to extract that handling into a service and use a mutex to make sure your code block that reads and then writes to the cache can only run in one thread at a time.

You could try using the lock. you could define a static lock object (private static readonly object _cacheLock = new object();). Use this lock to synchronize access to the cache: retrieve or initialize the list, modify it, and update the cache—all within a lock block. This will help to check that only one thread can modify the list at any time. one thing to note with this way you might face performance issue with high load

Thank you for the hint with the mutex as a service. This worked out very well.
